# Combining two bash commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If found this code

```
host raspberrypi | grep 'address' | cut -d' ' -f4
```

which gives pi Ip address

and this

```
wget --post-data="PiIP=1.2.3.4" http://dweet.io/dweet/for/cycy42
```

which sends 1.2.3.4 off to dweet.io stream

How can I get the output from 1st to replace the 1.2.3.4 in second please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the output of the first command in a variable:

```
ip=$(host raspberrypi | grep 'address' | cut -d' ' -f4)
wget --post-data="PiIP=$ip" http://dweet.io/dweet/for/cycy42
```

Btw, if your raspberrypi is running raspbian,
then a much cleaner way to get the IP address:

```
hostname -I
```

Simplifying the commands to:

```
ip=$(hostname -I)
wget --post-data="PiIP=$ip" http://dweet.io/dweet/for/cycy42
```

Making that a one-liner:

```
wget --post-data="PiIP=$(hostname -I)" http://dweet.io/dweet/for/cycy42
```

**UPDATE**

So it seems `hostname -I` gives a bit different output for you.
You can use this then:

```
ip=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')
```

To make it a one-liner, you can insert this into the second line just like I did in the earlier example.

Comment: BTW hostname -I gives me 192.168.0.35 fd36:c211:4785:0:3ce3:ed63:ecfb:fe1b fd36:c211:4785:0:213:efff:fe80:2658

Comment: Yes - it works :) wget --post-data="PiIP=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $1}')" http://dweet.io/dweet/for/cycy42